# Show a background grid (a.k.a. cells) when drawing a graph with networkx

Tags: python, graph, grid, networkx

I'm using networkx to draw a graph of a network with nodes at given positions on a field. The field is divided into a set amount of cells and the node positions correspond to a cell. When drawing the graph, I would like to show a grid in the background so the cells and distances in the graph are visible. Does networkx offer an option for that? I could not find one. I tried setting the grid via pyplot:

```
plt.xlim(0,14)
plt.ylim(0,10)
plt.xticks([x for x in xrange(0,14)])
plt.yticks([x for x in xrange(0,10)])
plt.grid(True)
```

which works by itself (see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dNUA.jpg)) but when also calling

```
nx.draw(G, pos)
```

it shows the graph without the grid (see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DcJuZ.jpg)). I'm guessing the grid is still in the background but networkx draws completely over it.

So is there any way to show the grid with plt or maybe a networkx command that I didn't find which allows something similar?

edit: Here is the complete code used. See the difference when (un)commenting `nx.draw(G,pos)`

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx


def quit_figure(event):
    if event.key == 'q':
        plt.close(event.canvas.figure)

nodes = [[1,1],[3,1],[6,1],[3,2],[13,1],[3,5]]
distance_array = [
    [[],[],[1,3],[],[5],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]],
    [[],[3],[0],[2],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]],
    [[],[],[],[1,3],[5],[],[],[4],[],[],[],[],[],[]],
    [[],[1],[0],[2,5],[],[],[],[],[],[],[10],[],[],[],[]],
    [[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[2],[],[],[3,5],[],[],[],[]],
    [[],[],[],[3],[0,2],[],[],[],[],[],[4],[],[],[],[],[]],
    [[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]],
    [[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]],
    [[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]]]

current_transmission_range = 0
transmission_range = np.zeros((len(nodes)), dtype=int)

pos = {x:[nodes[x][0],nodes[x][1]] for x in xrange(len(nodes))}
graph_nodes = [x for x in xrange(len(nodes))]


current_transmission_range = 0
cid = plt.gcf().canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', quit_figure)
plt.xlim(0,14)
plt.ylim(0,10)
plt.xticks([x+0.5 for x in xrange(0,14)], ['        '+str(x) for x in xrange(0,13)])
plt.yticks([x+0.5 for x in xrange(0,10)], ['\n\n'+str(x)+'\n\n\n\n' for x in xrange(0,9)])
plt.grid(True)

G = nx.Graph()
for node in graph_nodes:
    G.add_node(node)
for node in graph_nodes:
    for j in xrange(transmission_range[node]+1):
        for k in distance_array[node][j]:
            if(j <= current_transmission_range):
                G.add_edge(node, k,weight=j)

edge_weight=dict([((u,v,),int(d['weight'])) for u,v,d in G.edges(data=True)])
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, pos,edge_labels=edge_weight)
# draw graph
# nx.draw(G, pos)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Have you tried the [`hold` argument](http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw.html#networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw)?

Comment: Just tried it, didn't change anything. But I just saw theres an `ax` argument, that should probably help. Just have to figure out how exactly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use plt.grid('on')

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G = nx.path_graph(4)
nx.draw_networkx(G)
plt.grid('on')
plt.show()
```

If you want to use `nx.draw(G)` instead of `nx.draw_networkx(G)` you must also turn on the axis with `plt.axis('on')`.

[image]

Comment: That worked, thanks a lot! It does not work with `nx.draw(G)` though, I had to change to `nx.draw_networkx(G)` (as you suggested). Maybe you could change your first sentence to "use `plt.grid('on')` and `nx.draw_networkx(G)`" so it's clearer.

Answer (score 0):

[NetworkX's `draw` explicitly turns off axis](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/blob/ab9381394b21c1b8f6532d08b349336ffce6c65b/networkx/drawing/nx_pylab.py#L131).

You can avoid using `draw` and call the drawing subfunctions instead:

```
#...
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G,pos)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G,pos)
plt.show()
```

Or use `draw_networkx`, as Aric suggested.

That approach would be recommended if you're looking for long-term control over the drawing (as the `draw` implementation may change).

Of course, if it doesn't worry you, you can simply do `plt.axes().set_axis_on()` right after calling `draw`

[image]